# Is adding fields in a nested protobuf message backwards compatible?

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers

I have a protobuf message roughly like this:

```
syntax = "proto3";
package state;

message Version
{
  uint32 major = 1;
  uint32 minor = 2;
  uint32 fix = 3;
}

message Parameters
{
  optional int32 a = 1;
  optional int32 b = 2;
  optional bool c = 3;
  optional float d = 4;
}

/** A simple tree data structure to hold some state information */
message Tree
{
  /** All state value attributes for this node, as a name/value pair map */
  map<string, bytes> attributes = 1;

  /** All child state trees as a child id / Tree pair map */
  map<string, Tree> child_trees = 2;
}

message State
{
  string product_name = 1;
  Version product_version = 2;

  Parameters parameters = 3;

  Tree state_tree_a = 4;
  Tree state_tree_b = 5;
}
```

This is already used in shipped software. Now we would like to add further `optional` fields to the `Parameters` message (all of them either `bool`, `int` or `float`). This has to be backwards compatible, e.g. a new version of the software should be able to parse a `State` message written with the older version, where there were less entries in the nested `Parameters` message. The messages are serialised in C++ via `SerializeToArray` and restored via `ParseFromArray`.

I did some tests and this seems to work without problems. Extending the `Parameters` message did not break the readability of the `Tree` messages after it and fields not defined in the first version just returned `false` when checked for existence.

But I won't rely on this limiting amount of try and error testing for shipping code, so I'd like to find some documentation on wether this should be safe by design or if it just worked by pure luck in my tests or only under certain circumstances. In this case, it would be completely okay for me if it worked in a C++ context only.

From my understanding, the [Updating A Message Type section from the proto3 language guide](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto3#updating) does not give a clear answer wether it is safe or not to extend a message which sits nested in the middle of another message without risking to invalidate the data located behind it. But I might be overlooking something or getting something wrong from the documentation. Can anyone point me to a clearly documented answer to my question?

Comment: It is straight up written in the link you provided: "If you add new fields, any messages serialized by code using your "old" message format can still be parsed by your new generated code. You should keep in mind the default values for these elements so that new code can properly interact with messages generated by old code. Similarly, messages created by your new code can be parsed by your old code: old binaries simply ignore the new field when parsing. See the Unknown Fields section for details."

Comment: I understand adding fields to mean adding a field with a field number not used by the message yet. Now when extending the `Parameters` message, I'm pretty confident that this is covered by that rule. However at the scope of the `State` message I consider my change to be no addition, since I'm not adding anything but rather changing the type of a field from an old definition of `Parameters` to a new definition of `Parameters`. To me, the documentations are not clear on what generally happens when changing the type of a field, except for some explicit cases mentioned there.

Comment: you think it uses different routines for serializing/deserializing the same object? Uses one thing for "root" message another for when it isn't? Why would anyone do it? If that was the case at least they should've mentioned and differentiated root message with other types of messages.